# How to retrieve entities with a subset of related entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two entities in a one-to-many relation:
Meter (1) -> (n) Reading

I believe my two entities are set up correctly to provide the relation, so assume that.

I wish to retrieve Meters with related Readings but because there may be many Readings per Meter, I wish to limit it by eg Reading.Date. Another option could be to read at most X Readings per Meter.

How can I do that in EF.Core?

Comment: if your entities are set up correctly then when get a meter from your database, you get the list of readings for this meter along with the meter entity

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul: The question is how to retrieve a **subset** of related entities (i.e. not the entire set of related entities). Also, you should post attempted answers as answers, not as comments.

Comment: @Flater I wrote this comment to get a better understanding of the question, who said its an attempted answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think the other answer missed is that you are asking for a **subset** of the related entities, i.e. not the entire collection of related entities.

If you want to be selective about the related entities that are fetched, you cannot just rely on an `Include` statement (or implicit lazy loading), because these are set up to load all related entities.

There is no selective `Include`. But you can make an inclusive `Select`:

```
DateTime filterDate = DateTime.Now;

var myData = db.Meters
               .Select(m => new 
                            { 
                                Meter = m, 
                                Readings = m.Readings.Where(r => r.Date == filterDate)
                            })
               .ToList();
```

Remarks

- I used an anonymous type, but you can of course also use a concrete DTO class.
- `Where(r => r.Date == filterDate)` can be improved (checking for the `Date` component, or a range), this is just a simple example. You can use whatever filter criteria you want here.
- Notice that you do not need an `Include` statement for this. A `Select` (on a yet unenumerated `IQueryable`) does not need an explicit `Include` because the `Select` itself is already aware of what data you want to fetch.
- I suggest not putting the subset of related entities in the `meter.Readings` nav prop. This is going to lead to confusion down the line as to whether this list is a subset or the full set, and EF may actually register this as a change when you call `SaceChanges()`. Nav props should not be used as storage space for collection with the same type but a different functional meaning.

Comment: Fast response - thanks! And indeed you read the question correctly, this is what I need :)

Would this result in a single query/roundtrip to the database?

Comment: @AndersJuul: Yes, as long as the `Select` happens before the IQueryable is enumerated. If that is not the case, you will either run into a nullreference (eager loading) or a second query (lazy loading).

Answer (score -1):

If your tables are designed correctly i.e. key in Meter is mapped with Reading (see foreign key constraints), then EF automatically gives related records when you access its POCO class. 
Make sure Reading has foreign key for Meter table in database.

Comment: The question is how to retrieve a **subset** of related entities (i.e. not the entire set of related entities). Your answer doesn't answer that.